# Why simple console.log() doesn't works with while?

Tags: javascript, html, while-loop, console.log

Today, I made a classic "99 bottles" with JavaScript.it's working when document.write() is used.But when I use console.log(), it behaves strangely.

console.log() code-----

```
 var word = "bottles";
 var count = 99;
 while (count > 0) {
 console.log(count + " " + word + " of beer on the wall");
 console.log(count + " " + word + " of beer,");
 console.log("Take one down, pass it around,");
 count = count - 1;


}
 console.log("No more " + word + " of beer on the wall.");
```

The above code should start with "99 bottles.....".But it's starting with "67 bottles....".Why this is happening?
fiddle-http://jsfiddle.net/vashuStrPro/9dobfj8h/

Comment: In the code above, I can't see any `console.log`s

Comment: it does start at 99.

Comment: Your demo works just fine for me.

Comment: I was able to use your fiddle and see "99 bottles..." in my console.

Comment: oh sorry, i wrote document.write one..

Comment: The console is not there to be a persistent storage of 300 lines of logs. So the implementation of the console is free to limit the stored, visible lines.

Comment: It does start with "99 bottles of beer on the wall".

Comment: Which browser / debugging tool are you using, and how many lines can the console buffer handle?

Comment: i am using mozilla firefox developer edition

Comment: Because you already took the 32 bottles down? Your fiddle is working for me too, so you probably didn't scroll your console up or something like that. EDIT: Yeah, FF console is stupid. Use Chrome.

Comment: working fine [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vashuStrPro/9dobfj8h/)

Comment: Problem occurs in mozilla and works fine in chrome ..

Comment: Working fine in chrome here

Comment: Yes, the problem exists in Firefox only.It's working fine now in Chrome.But does anyone knows how can it be implemented in Firefox?

Comment: The problem is not with code but with the console capacity of browser as said by Edi G. in da House. you can also store the values in array and then console the array as                   while (count >= 0) {
arr[count]=count;
count = count - 1;
}
console.log(arr);

Comment: that was it... @Alok

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the limit of your developer-console.. not your Code..

i have update your Code -> it append your text to a divcontainer... start 99 end 1

JavaScript:

```
var word = "bottles";
var div = document.getElementById('tmp');

for (var count = 99; count > 0; --count) {
    div = document.getElementById('tmp');
    div.innerHTML = div.innerHTML + count + " " + word + " of beer on the wall<br>";
    div.innerHTML = div.innerHTML + count + " " + word + " of beer,<br>";
    div.innerHTML = div.innerHTML + "Take one down, pass it around,<br>";
}

div.innerHTML = div.innerHTML + "No more " + word + " of beer on the wall.";
```

HTML:

```
<div id="tmp">
</div>
```

Answer after Comment:

FireFox

Type `about:config` into the address bar and select ok to the dragons.

type this into the filter

```
devtools.hud.loglimit.console
```

there you can set your limit...

Comment: well, i want a way so that i can increase the limit of console.log()